# Pandas - Problemas com ".loc[]" em múltiplas entradas

Tags: python, pandas

Meu projeto possui 4 inputs dado pelo usuário que são armazenados nas variáveis a, b, c, d.

Uso essas entradas para filtrar informações vindas de um .csv gigante, armazenando-as em um dataframe. O filtro é feito usando "loc[]", da seguinte forma:

```
arquivo = chunk.loc[(chunk['Coluna1'] == a) & (chunk['Coluna2'] == b) & (chunk['Coluna3'] == c) & (chunk['Coluna4'] == d)]
```

O problema é que o usuário pode ou não preencher os 4 inputs. Preciso que o método "loc" seja capaz de filtrar informações mesmo quando por exemplo, o usuário dê input na variável "a" e deixe as outras em branco.

Da maneira que montei, as variáveis que não receberam informações, recebem o a string: "". O ".loc[]" então tenta achar linhas onde a coluna em questão tem "".

Pensei que uma solução possível, seria atribuir um "valor coringa" às variáveis não preenchidas, porém não sei se isso é possível.

Answer (score 0):

Creio que isso possa ser feito não na chamada do `loc`, mas sim quando você obtém as variáveis pelo usuário. Primeiro, precisamos considerar uma entrada que o usuário não forneceu como `None`. Atualmente, você está considerando uma string vazia (`''`). Precisamos então convertê-la:

```
def retorna_variavel(nome):
    # Insira aqui o código para obter a entrada do usuário pela interface
    # gráfica. Estou assumindo que a entrada esteja sendo obtida por meio
    # de uma caixa de texto por exemplo, portanto ela será do tipo string
    texto = retorna_variavel_de_caixa_de_texto(nome)

    # Verifica se o usuário não digitou nada. Essa verificação é equivalente
    # à `if texto is None or len(texto) == 0:`
    if not texto:
        return None
    
    # Converte a variável inserida pelo usuário para um tipo inteiro. Você
    # também pode convertê-la para o tipo ponto flutuante utilizando `float`. 
    return int(texto)
```

Em seguida, você cria as variáveis `a`, `b`, `c` e `d` desejadas:

```py
a = retorna_variavel('a')
b = retorna_variavel('b')
c = retorna_variavel('c')
d = retorna_variavel('d')
```

Por fim, você pode utilizar o seguinte código para filtrar o `pd.DataFrame`:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Um DataFrame de exemplo
chunk = pd.DataFrame({
    'Coluna1': [1, 1],
    'Coluna2': [2, 2],
    'Coluna3': [3, 3],
    'Coluna4': [5, 6],
})

arquivo = chunk.loc[
    (a is None or chunk['Coluna1'] == a) & 
    (b is None or chunk['Coluna2'] == b) & 
    (c is None or chunk['Coluna3'] == c) & 
    (d is None or chunk['Coluna4'] == d)]
    
print(arquivo)
```

Neste exemplo,

- caso `a == 1`, `b == 2`, `c == 3` e `d == 4`, a saída será

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Coluna1, Coluna2, Coluna3, Coluna4]
Index: []
```

- caso `a == 1`, `b == 2`, `c == 3` e `d == 5`, a saída será

```
   Coluna1  Coluna2  Coluna3  Coluna4
0        1        2        3        5
```

- caso `a == 1`, `b == 2`, `c == 3` e `d == 6`, a saída será

```
   Coluna1  Coluna2  Coluna3  Coluna4
1        1        2        3        6
```

- caso `a == 1`, `b == 2`, `c == 3` e `d == None` (o usuário omitiu o valor de `d`), a saída será

```
   Coluna1  Coluna2  Coluna3  Coluna4
0        1        2        3        5
1        1        2        3        6
```

Como `d` foi omitido, todos os valores da coluna 4 foram retornados.

Comment: Essas entradas são dadas por uma interface gráfica. Necessariamente recebo valores para todas as 4, porém as que não são preenchidas, recebo: "".

Na minha lógica, precisava que a função loc ignorasse as variáveis não preenchidas, mas não estou conseguindo pensar num jeito de fazer isso...

A variável coringa que quis dizer, seria um valor pelo qual a função loc buscaria na respectiva coluna, mas que trouxesse qualquer coisa, entende?

Comment: Entendi, peço desculpas pelo mal entendido. Atualizei a minha resposta, veja se isso resolve seu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer o teste iterativamente?
Por exemplo, assumindo que seu DataFrame tenha as colunas `v_a, v_b, v_c e v_d` e as variáveis que vc recebeu são `a, b, c e d` que podem ou não ser iguais a `""`:

```
df_filtrado=df_original
for (col,valor) in {'v_a':a,'v_b':b,'v_c':c,'v_d':d}.items():
    if valor != "":
        df_filtrado=df_filtrado[df_filtrado[col]==valor]
```

Ao final, seu DataFrame filtado terá aplicado os filtros desejados apenas quando eles forem diferentes de "".

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).